# ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);]' command failed

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run one project in react native, but i am getting the next error

> :ReactNative:Running '[node, -e,
> console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);]' command failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/Users/test/Documents/testA/react/app-test/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'
>   line: 179
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script.
>
> > Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/Users/test/Documents/testA/react/app-test/test/android"):
> > error=2, No such file or directory
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
>   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
>   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
>   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution,

1. Run android studio as administrator
2. Open the project with android studio
3. Close the android studio
4. Open again the project with android studio but it is not neccesary as administrator